# Magento 2 require js throw error

Tags: magento2, requirejs

Magento 2 require js throw error

I am using Magento 2.2.0

```
var config = {
    paths: {            
            'owlcarousel': "Module_Banners/js/owl.carousel.min",
            'custom': "Module_Banners/js/sp_banner"
        },   
    shim: {
        'owlcarousel': {
            deps: ['jquery']
        }
    }
};
```

> Uncaught Error: Script error for: owlcarousel
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
>       at makeError (require.js:166)
>       at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)

Comment: We need more information where you use the owl carousel

Comment: In my custom Module Root folder i create like this requirejs-config.js

Comment: Did you run deploy command?

Comment: Yes I run ......